# zipf and correlated lognormal

Tags: probability, distributions, random-variable, lognormal-distribution, copula

I have been struggling with this for a while. I want to generate two random variables $X$ and $Y$ with a particular correlation $\rho$ where $X$ is the file popularity (zipf distribution) and $Y$ is the file size (lognormal). For example, let $N_{f}=4$ be the number of files. Then,$X=1,2,3,4$ where $X=1$ and $X=4$ are the most and least popular files. Note that each file has to be associated with one file size. For example, a possible set is $(X,Y)=(1,3),(2,10),(3,2),(4,5)$.

Comment: any help is highly appreciated

Comment: You could ask it in stackoverflow aswell